# Как поймать событие нештатного закрытия сокета при чтении данных через ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, сокет

Т.е. я читаю данные на сервере:

```
while(true) {
    reader  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    try {
        Object message = reader.readUnshared();

        //
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) { }
    catch (IOException ex) { }
}
```

У клиента обрывается интернет, естественно сокет до сих пор открыт. При записи в этот сокет никакой ошибки не поисходит, что странно.

Если мы добавляем `setSoTimeout()` то это принуждает всё время передавать данные.

Если мы переводим на `InputStreamReader`, то опять же должны получать `-1` как информацию о закрытии сокета, но текущий вопрос это не решает.

Так как же тогда определить, что клиент таки отвалился?

Comment: Периодически отправлять клиенту какое-нибудь keep-alive сообщение.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, я писал об этом. Меня интересует, есть ли какой-нибудь еще другой способ?

Comment: Keep-alive сообщения - это самый надёжный.